# Counting the number of rows for all columns in views within SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I am hoping someone could help or provide insight. I am working on automating the way we audit our **database views**. The goal is to quickly see which columns are empty in which views. I started to work on a script but ran into different issues. All of the examples with this script run, but produce results that I did not intended. Right now some column headers have titles with a space in between.

Since I am fairly new to this, I am unsure what I am doing wrong or even how to obtain the results I am looking for.

Thank you in advance for your help!

- Example 1 - Runs but produces Nulls
- Example 2 - Runs but produces 0s,
- Example 3 – Runs and produces counts for the entire view rather than
  for the column itself (i.e. it gave the max amount of rows in the
  view).

```
------------------------------------
-- EXAMPLE 1: 
-- Did not produce the results expected.
-- Issue is it returns all as NULL
---------------------------------------\
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempColumnCount;

CREATE TABLE #tempColumnCount
(
    Name        VARCHAR(100),
    Row_Count   INT
);

Declare     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET         @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO #tempColumnCount SELECT '''  + c.name + ''' as Name, SUM (CASE WHEN ''' +  c.name +
                    ''' IS NULL THEN 1 END)  FROM ' + schema_name(v.schema_id) + '.' +  OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)  +
                    CHAR(13) 
                    FROM sys.columns  c
                    JOIN sys.views v 
                        ON v.object_id = c.object_id AND SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id)='analytics'
exec (@SQL)

SELECT     Name, Row_Count
FROM        #tempColumnCount


---------------------------------------\
-- Example 2: Issue is it returns all as 0
---------------------------------------\
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempColumnCount;

CREATE TABLE #tempColumnCount
(
    Name        VARCHAR(100),
    Row_Count   INT
);

Declare     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET         @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO #tempColumnCount SELECT '''  + c.name + ''' as Name, COUNT(1) - COUNT(''' +  c.name +
                    ''' )  FROM ' + schema_name(v.schema_id) + '.' +  OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)  +
                    CHAR(13) 
                    FROM sys.columns  c
                    JOIN sys.views v 
                        ON v.object_id = c.object_id AND SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id)='analytics'
exec (@SQL)

SELECT     Name, Row_Count
FROM        #tempColumnCount


---------------------------------------\
-- Example 3: Issue is it returns the the max amount of rows for each column. Which just means it returns the row count for the whole view and not the column it self. 
---------------------------------------\
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempColumnCount;

CREATE TABLE #tempColumnCount
(
    Name        VARCHAR(100),
    Row_Count   INT
);

Declare     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET         @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO #tempColumnCount SELECT '''  + c.name + ''' as Name, COUNT(''' +  c.name +
                    ''' )  FROM ' + schema_name(v.schema_id) + '.' +  OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)  +
                    CHAR(13) 
                    FROM sys.columns  c
                    JOIN sys.views v 
                        ON v.object_id = c.object_id AND SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id)='analytics'
exec (@SQL)

SELECT     Name, Row_Count
FROM        #tempColumnCount
```

Comment: In every example the issue is too many quotes. You're constantly comparing the literal string `'some_column_name'` to `null`, or counting it for each row. As a general rule, you should always write a working query before making it dynamic. And you should always parameterize your dynamic query, if only to force the habit. Finally, `print @SQL` is your best friend.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: I would really like a simple explanation and example of what would be a valid result set.  I appreciate the effort in three different methods, but don't fully understand what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. @GordonLinoff The script should look through all the 70 views and provide a row count for the column it self in a similar way as: select count (column_name) from schema.viewname. Instead I get the results that look like this select count (*) from schema.viewname. Example of how the a valid result:

**View: ColName: RowCount:**
- View 1  Description  23
- View 1  Year  34 
- View 1  InstanceSetKey 32 
- View 2  Term  23 
- View 3  Subject 5

All the columns in views should have different counts since NULLs are valid within them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you @HoneyBadger It is a rational sql database currently being managed with Microsoft SQL server management studio. I included additional quotes was because some columns contain a space. Example of a column: "Active Users" instead of "ActiveUsers". When running the code, it gave errors with those columns. How do you address this without adding additional quotes?

Comment: A single quote is for a literal string, double quotes are for identifiers. Sql server uses `[]`. In sql server you can use `quotename`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: @HoneyBadger thank you! this solved the issue! I appreciate the insight you provided!